# how to limit user access to multiple active currencies?

Tags: multi-currency

## Multi-currency : Hi All,

My org is Multi currency enabled and has USD as the corporate currency.
Besides that i have Euro and AUD as additional active currency. On a particular user's detail the default currency is set to Euro. the User do not need access to USD. but on a custom object, currency field all the 3 currencies are available with euro as the first item. how can i remove access to USD from the currency picklist for the user?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, it is not possible to limit the values in the currency picklist (for a multi-currency enabled scenario). [A similar idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrcFAAS) is under point threshold though - this when implemented will allow you to limit specific currency values based on record type.